# java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-test, java-17

java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist
java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist
java: cannot find symbol symbol: class SpringBootTest

java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Test
location: class com.shri.Chat.ChatApplicationTests

These are the errors, can not figure out why? Please refer to my pom.xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.shri</groupId>
    <artifactId>Chat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Chat</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot chat application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I believe all dependencies are listed properly for test, using intelliJ for first time

Comment: Does that happen if you build on plain command line or within your IDE?

Comment: I believe it is within IDE

Comment: Do you use the most recent version of IntelliJ?

Comment: yes it is latest and my first project. Apologies for late reply, busy with other project

Comment: Is this class `com.shri.Chat.ChatApplicationTests` the test? Where have you located that class? `src/test/java`??